# Trying to create numpy array of images, but I get X_data shape: (0,)

Tags: arrays, image, numpy

I have 10 black/white images in a folder that look like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNTWU.png) I'm trying to save all of these into a numpy array. But, I get the following result: X_data shape: (0,)

```
import cv2
import glob
import numpy as np

X_data = []
files = glob.glob ("Documents/MATLAB/attempt6images/*.jpg")
for myFile in files:
    print(myFile)
    image = cv2.imread (myFile)
    X_data.append (image)

print('X_data shape:', np.array(X_data).shape)
```

Comment: See [Appending a numpy array to a list - strange happenings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53824618/appending-a-numpy-array-to-a-list-strange-happenings)

Comment: can you try this `np.stack(X_data, axis=0).shape`?